# Geocoder not working by getfromlocationName

Tags: java, google-geocoder

My code is as below:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this,Locale.UK );
         List<Address> addresses = null;
         Toast.makeText(displaybyName.this, "country: before " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
   try {
    Toast.makeText(displaybyName.this, "country: before " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName( 
      "Camden", 1);

    if (addresses.size() > 0) {

           geopoint = new GeoPoint(
                         (int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                         (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6));

           //Animating on display

           mapcontroller.animateTo(geopoint);
           mapcontroller.setZoom(5); 
           mapview.invalidate();
          } 


   } catch (IOException io) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    Toast.makeText(displaybyName.this, "Connection Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

   if (addresses.size() > 0) {

          geopoint = new GeoPoint(
                        (int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                        (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6));

          //Animating on display

          mapcontroller.animateTo(geopoint);
          mapcontroller.setZoom(5); 
          mapview.invalidate();
         }
```

However, the app is crashing each time. The geocoder is not returning any lat/long.

Is there any issue with the codes...plz plz advise.

Comment: "crashing" - we need more details on the failure (description, stack trace, ...)

Comment: You really need to find the error in your LogCat window (on the DDMS perspective if you cannot see it otherwise)

Comment: Also, you seem to have your IF logic repeated, once inside the try-catch and once afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Double check that

```
addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName("Camden", 1);
```

returns something that isn't `null` - otherwise: the following line will raise an `NullPointerException`

---

**Further Reading**

- [geocoder.getFromLocationName returns only null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567216/geocoder-getfromlocationname-returns-only-null)

Comment: Thanks, i tried several different address but still my app is crashing. I have checked the permissions on Manifest files and it seems to be okie.. I have some addresses from london city and needs to get its coordinates to be able to display it on the map. Is there any other way i can do this because the geocoder function is not working.

Comment: When trying to get a coordinates out of an address,the program is crashing on the emulator.I cannot see an error. The Geocoder class requires a backend service that is not included in the core android framework. Sooo, i am confuzed now. What do I have to call, import, add, use in code.... to make this work? I am using Google Api2.2, Api level 8. If somebody has found a solution for this, or a pointer for documentation, something that i didn't discover, please let us know. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

There is android version problem because geocoder doesn't come with the core android framework but this will work fine on old and new versions like on 1.6, 2.0 and API level 15 try these first it will definitely work but still insisting on just try your
own geocoder class using JSON.