# Get intersection latitude and longitude using geocoder in Android application

Tags: android, latitude-longitude, intersection, google-geocoder

I'm trying to find the latitude and the longitude of a given intersection in an android application, using `geocoder`:

```
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName("Terrace St & Darragh St, Pittsburgh, PA", 1);
```

This query returns always `null`, even if I replace the '&' with 'and'.

How do I solve this? Does geocoder provide this information?

Comment: Not sure but your context that your are passing to Geocoder is correct? Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567216/geocoder-getfromlocationname-returns-only-null answer ?

Comment: Yes I did: using an address (like "Terrace St, Pittsburgh, PA") works, it doesn't work only on the intersection. Instead the Google Geocoding API works perfectly: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Terrace+St+and+Darragh+St,+Pittsburgh+,+PA&sensor=false