# Android 6.0 getFromLocationName no result

Tags: android

I try to get address from android.location.Geocode. Below is the code:

// Grant whatever permission I think is related

```
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
            Manifest.permission.VIBRATE,
            Manifest.permission.INTERNET},100);
```

// Request Geocode service. Function: provide an address to addressStr. Expected output: address related information, e.g. latitude, longtitude

import android.location.Geocoder;
...

```
String addressStr = "#3140-4000 No.3 Rd, Richmond, BC Canada";
Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(mContext);
    List<Address> address;
    address = coder.getFromLocationName(addressStr, 1);
System.out.println(address.size());
```

//Output in mobile device: 0

Result:

1. Run on a Android device - the address.size() always 0 (PROBLEM here!)
2. Run on a Android emulator - result normal

coder.isPresent() always return true in above situation.

As the same piece of code working fine in emulator. And it worked in pass few days when I first created this app. I guess google provide free service to emulator, and a certain free quota to actual device. Once the free quota used up, it won't work in actual device anymore. But still work in emulator

Any comment on my guessing?

Comment: I would like to see more code, and Logcat too

Comment: the logcat too large to be posted here. any way I can show you?

Comment: 04-03 22:07:46.059 32063-32063/jianrongmo.com.comp3617.finalproject.savenet I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.widget.HwCustTextViewImpl
04-03 22:07:46.088 32063-32213/jianrongmo.com.comp3617.finalproject.savenet I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
04-03 22:07:46.543 32063-32225/jianrongmo.com.comp3617.finalproject.savenet I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
04-03 22:07:47.520 32063-32240/jianrongmo.com.comp3617.finalproject.savenet I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
04-03 22:07:47.612 32063-

Comment: OK I got it. It seems that it was Geocoder bug. You could review from this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567216/geocoder-getfromlocationname-returns-only-null